# Get all Elements touching a rectangle

Tags: javascript

I need to get all elements whose bounding rectangle intersects some arbitrary rectangle of my choosing. I'm not aware of a way to do this natively, and my best solution so far is to call [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) on a representative sample of points inside the rectangle, which is far from perfect, as it could miss elements.

Running it on every point in the rectangle would be a performance nightmare, and therefore is not an option. Even if that was feasible, I don't think it would catch elements with `width: 0; height: 0`, although that's not a *huge* concern for me.

I have ideas on how to minimize false negatives using the many-points method, but is there a *real* solution?

Comment: Can the rectangles rotate?

Comment: You might get some ideas from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5t6t/1/).

Comment: @Shomz The rectangle I'm checking against? For simplicity's sake, let's say all sides are parallel to the respective edges of the viewport.

Comment: Did you find  a proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the [bounding rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) for every element that may touch your rectangle.
2. For each element, check whether the bounding rectangle and your rectangle intersect.

If you have a huge number of elements, and you can make assumptions like 'the bounding rects of an element's child elements are always contained in the element's bounding rect', then there are some optimizations possible. Or when the elements are ordered in a certain way. But if any position is possible for any HTML element, as CSS allows, you need to check them all.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't be fast enough; the algorithm has to work for very large documents.

Comment: @QuinnStrahl Can you assume that an element's children boundaries are inside the elements boundaries? Do you have a tree of elements or do you have a flat structure with many elements at the same level? Or are they sorted in some way?
I am afraid that there is no native solution, but there are certainly ways to optimize the process.

Comment: The problem domain is any arbitrary DOM tree, so I can't assume a child's boundaries are inside its parent's. It could also therefore be a tree of virtually any size and structure. Oh well.

Comment: I see. How often does it change? Is there only a limited number of changes? Then you could sort or structure the bounding rects and re-use that.

Comment: It might never change, it might change forever at random intervals, and everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

If they are parallel, then you'll be good with just having four parameters defined for each rectangle: x, y, width and height. Comparing them each is now **much, much** less performance-consuming than using single points, and you'll always get accurate results.

Comment: This would require iterating over every element in the document though, correct? I'm concerned that just won't be fast enough if not implemented natively.

Comment: Yes, it goes over every element. Hmm, I'm not sure about how exactly you're implementing this, but here's an optimization idea: if you can, you can build an array of rectangles (each rectangle would be an array with the 4 parameters I mentioned in my answer... also, why not an object? because arrays are much faster) when the document loads, and on every item position change (if that's a possibility). So now, instead of iterating over many DOM elements, you're iterating over an array, which is probably the fastest you can get in JavaScript, and it's easy to test as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't rely on MutationObserver or DOM mutation events as this code will have to run natively in old and terrible browsers.